# Does Neo-Vedanta reject Dharma Shastras? If so, why?

Tags: dharma-shastras, vivekananda, neo-vedanta

Do [Neo-Vedantins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Vedanta) reject the authority of the Dharma Shastras? If so, why?

Comment: It is very simple. They wanted to propagate Vedantic knowledge to everyone. We all know Dharma sastras constrains upanayana rights to particular Varnas. So, they rejected. They even rejected verses from Brahma Sutras which deny Jnana to lower Varna peoples.

Comment: They say Vedas have more authority over smritis (Dharma sastras) and they often cite Yajurveda 26.2 to prove that anyone can learn Vedas.

Comment: Again, there are no sects or groups that identify themselves as 'neo-Vedantins'. This term was invented by Western Christian orientalists to denigrate the Hindu religion.

Comment: This is not the site to denigrate particular sect or group of people.

Comment: Term "Neo-Vedanta" is not recognized by Hindus. Western Orientalists coined that word to denigrate Hinduism. Better if you avoid using that. Be respectful to all sects.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda What would you guys call the sect that follows the teachings of Swami Vivekananda? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Vedanta

Comment: @TheDestroyer What would you guys call the sect that follows the teachings of Swami Vivekananda? en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Vedanta

Comment: @Ikshvaku There's no specific name for sect of Vivekananda. Different Hindus can have different views. Paul hacker coined Neo-Vedanta for spread of Christianity and obviously wiki has western bias. Scholars like Rajiv Malhotra refuted this in his book "Indra's net". You can ask questions without using word "Neo-vedanta" as it is controversial term.

Comment: Just a 3rd eye observation. I see people have flagged this as offtopic. It would be good if people can clarify what is offtopic about this or what is disrespectful in the question in the first place.

Comment: explain what dharma shastras you mean

Comment: @Pandya Everyone knows this is not the site to denigrate particular sect or people but how is your comment relevant here? I don't see your comment validity due to the course of event. See the meta question. Many users and sect are feeling that the language used is offending but mods say that it is ok and one is offending to some people is not offending to other group of people. So, which group are you talking to here?

Comment: "Western Christian orientalists to denigrate the Hindu religion." – @Swami Vishwananda - totally wrong.  The name is irrelevant - it is modern, non-obscurantiist Hinduism.  The Christian threat is from a U.S. origin organization that has taken a monotheist Hindu sect's religion and is assiduously blending it with Christianity, exploiting Hindus' worship of white people.

Comment: Swami ﹰVivekananda never used the word 'neo-Vedanta'. He preferred the term 'practical Vedanta'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what Neo-Vedanta is, but I am answering with the views of Swami Vivekananda on the subject.

Source: [The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 3/Lectures from Colombo to Almora/The Sages of India.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_3/Lectures_from_Colombo_to_Almora/The_Sages_of_India)

> In the first place, we have to understand a little about our
>   scriptures. **Two ideals of truth are in our scriptures; the one is,
>   what we call the eternal, and the other is not so authoritative, yet
>   binding under particular circumstances, times, and places.** The eternal
>   relations which deal with the nature of the soul, and of God, and the
>   relations between souls and God are embodied in what we call the
>   Shrutis, the Vedas. The next set of truths is what we call the
>   Smritis, as embodied in the words of Manu. Yâjnavalkya, and other
>   writers and also in the Purânas, down to the Tantras. The second class
>   of books and teachings is subordinate to the Shrutis, inasmuch as
>   whenever any one of these contradicts anything in the Shrutis, the
>   Shrutis must prevail. This is the law. The idea is that the framework
>   of the destiny and goal of man has been all delineated in the Vedas,
>   the details have been left to be worked out in the Smritis and
>   Puranas. As for general directions, the Shrutis are enough; for
>   spiritual life, nothing more can be said, nothing more can be known.
>   All that is necessary has been known, all the advice that is necessary
>   to lead the soul to perfection has been completed in the Shrutis; the
>   details alone were left out, and these the Smritis have supplied from
>   time to time.

"and the **other is not so authoritative, yet
 binding** under particular circumstances, times, and places" -- That means he accepts that the other i.e the Dharmashastras of Manu etc are authoritative in certain times, places.. although not as authoritative as the Vedas..  So he does not completely reject the Smriti's authority.

Furthermore, he says:

> The second class of books and teachings is subordinate to the Shrutis,
>   inasmuch as whenever any one of these contradicts anything in the
>   Shrutis, the Shrutis must prevail. 
>   **This is the law.**

Now, this rule or law itself (that if Sruti contradicts a Smriti the later should be rejected) is not from the Vedas but found in the Smritis and Puranas. So, he is accepting the authority of Smritis and Puranas in this case too.

Comment: Yes I am not sure about Neo-Vedanta's view but for Vivekananda's view I can answer and if his views are the same as those Neo-Vedanta then I have answered the Q @Ikshvaku

Comment: Also that Wiki article is not helpful for my purpose because which are the texts for them that I will cite to give their views? I don't know any.. but If it is Swami Vivekananda's views I can quote from his works.. @Ikshvaku

Comment: Alright. Btw, does Swami Vivekananda think the Manusmriti and other Dharma Shastras are applicable today?

Comment: I hv not found such specific quotes yet .. @Ikshvaku

Comment: Excellent answer Rickross Ji

Answer (score 5):

I dont like the term Neo-Vedanta. But this is what Swami Vivekananda wrote in His introduction to Rajyoga:

> Each soul is potentially divine.
>
> The goal is to manifest this Divinity within by controlling nature, external and internal.
>
> Do this either by work, or worship, or psychic control, or philosophy — by one, or more, or all of these — and be free.
>
> This is the whole of religion. Doctrines, or dogmas, or rituals, or books, or temples, or forms, are but secondary details.

I feel this is the essence of true spirituality. This gives ME the essence of the Vedanta, the essence of Dharma and the essence and importance of the Dharma Shastras.

Swami Vivekananda's opinion in a letter written on 30 May 1887---just one year after His Guru's passing away also makes the role of the Dharma -sastras clear to ME:

> The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors, the feelings of class and malice. Only parts of them breathing broadness of spirit and love are acceptable, the rest are to be rejected. The Upanishads and the Gita are the true scriptures; Rama, Krishna, Buddha, Chaitanya, Nanak, Kabir, and so on are the true Avatâras, for they had their hearts broad as the sky — and above all, Ramakrishna.

I know of course that He was too young at that time, was very emotional and always had infinite compassion for all. So I take the last message by sprit, NOT by words.

Comment: You are right but here OP is asking about what he thought of the Dharmasastras .. so u may want to quote something from CW?

Comment: Neo-vedanta is just modern Smartism, or Hinduism without sharp elbows. @Partha Banerjee

Comment: Buddha is the only prophet who said, I do not care to know your various theories about God. What is the use of discussing all the subtle doctrines about the soul? Do good and be good.Pray all the time, read all the scriptures in the world, and worship all the gods there are …[but] unless you realize the Self (atman), there is no freedom.  -Swami Vivekananda

Comment: Point to note that Puranas were composed by the same person who has composed Gita .. So he will basically decide himself which to accept and which to reject :)

Comment: @Nitin thnx.but i find the love of God as described by Bhagavatam, Chaitanyadev, Sri Ramakrishna,Sri Ramprasd Sen, Meera and many others beyond comparison

Comment: @Rickross i think He took the Gita as words of God. This comment He made at annearly age but i find the essence true for ME

Comment: Than you are on right path, Tapas for Satyuga, Satya/Dharma for Treta, Shaucha/Yagya for Dwapra, and Bhakti for Kaliyuga is the way for liberation.

Comment: In that case Purans also has many such instances whr God is speaking in them .. his logic is not working for me :) @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: @Rickross no i think there is difference. see in bengal we worship Gita and Chandi but dont worship other puranas or scriptures with the same respect.Allopanishadc and Ishopanishad are both named upanishads but we know whats what

Comment: Too young in 1897? He was already 34 and 5 years later, he left the body.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria yes He left His body very early

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria i wd be 1887.sorry for typo

Comment: Because the purpose of his life was complete. He had introduced Hinduism in west, inspired many people, realized the highest truth, set up Ramakrishna Mission etc.. He had done everything in 39 years.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria  yes thats true and i havevcorrected it to 1887.thanks for pointing out