# Was Vivekananda a proponent of birth-based caste-system or the guṇa-based?

Tags: caste-system, manu-smriti, vivekananda, varna, purusha-sukta

What type of caste-system did Swami Vivekananda advocate? Birth-based or guṇa-based? And on what basis?

If he believed one's varṇa is determined by their guṇa:

- Did he reject smṛtis such as Manu which seem to advocate birth-based varṇāśrama?
- How did he interpret the Puruṣa-sūkta verse *brāhmaṇo 'sya mukham ... padbhyāṃ śūdro ajāyata* (brāhmaṇa was born from Puruṣa's mouth ... śūdra from his feet)?

Comment: The title Q is possibly a duplicate of [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26688/is-there-any-explicit-writing-by-swami-vivekananda-on-his-psychological-theory-o) .. for the first Q in the body [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32325/4732) is related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any explicit writing by Swami Vivekananda on his psychological theory of Varna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26688/is-there-any-explicit-writing-by-swami-vivekananda-on-his-psychological-theory-o)

Comment: Related, but not duplicate. The other question is vague, this is more explicit. @Rickross

Comment: The sub question "Did he reject smṛtis such as Manu which seem to advocate birth-based varṇāśrama?" is also a duplicate of --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31930/does-neo-vedanta-reject-dharma-shastras-if-so-why/32325#32325

Comment: You mean the sub-question here is answered there? But how does that make this question duplicate of the other question? This is specific to Vivekananda. The other one could've also been answered by citing another neo-Vedantin, e.g., Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan. It's just that you chose to answer using Vivekananda's works.

Comment: Ikshvaku is mainly looking to know Vivekananda's views on the matter. This is clear from the fact that he tagged his Q with Vivekananda and also from the fact that he considers neo-vedanta to be the sect followed by Vivekananda's followers (check his comments underneath that post). "But how does that make this question duplicate of the other question?" ---- If your Q is answered under another post and yet it is to be left open then why the template asks "Does this answer your question?"

Comment: 'Ikshvaku is mainly looking to know Vivekananda's views on the matter....check his comments underneath that post' - I didn't check the comments, whatever clarifications given in comments should usually be added to the question itself. I noticed the 'Vivekananda' tag on other question but still doesn't make it an exact duplicate. This question is specific to one neo-Vedantin, Vivekananda. @Rickross

Comment: From Wikipedia on [Neo-Vedanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Vedanta): "Among the main proponents of such modern interpretations of Hinduism were Vivekananda, Aurobindo and Radhakrishnan, who to some extent also contributed to the emergence of Neo-Hindu movements in the West." -- so I can ask the same question here two more times, one for Aurobindo and another for Radhakrishnan and they still won't be exact duplicates of [Does Neo-Vedanta reject Dharma Shastras? If so, why?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31930/does-neo-vedanta-reject-dharma-shastras-if-so-why) @Rickross

Comment: This looks like asking multiple questions. The question of interpreting Purusha Sukta verse should be asked separately.

Comment: [This Meta Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/260388) may be useful for understanding the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Although, it'd have been better if you had posted it before closing the question using your supervote. Asking multiple closely-related questions has never been a problem. The Help Center clearly says, "Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once." Note the word distinct. E.g., [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/42432) question is asking the difference between Taittiriya Samhita and Brahmana and also asking for an English translation. Since these two are closely related, it's not a big deal. @Pandya

Comment: I had read that MSE post earlier and the question clearly says: "but each question is independent from the others", this is the key. Here, one question follows the other, they are all linked to Vivekananda and caste-system. @Pandya

Comment: @sv. see [the edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/42432/revisions) to the question you mentioned.

Comment: What about your own question: [What are the Agama scriptures? Are they related to Shruti/Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12282/2995) Should it be closed as 'needs more focus' as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vivekananda advocated a return to a karma-guna based varna system and not the last name based jati system. Both the karma-guna based varna system and the last name based jati system are birth based. The present varna of a person is dependent on the past karma and guna in the karma-guna based varna system and a person can indeed transcend his varna through spiritual practice. The jati or caste of a person is decided by the last name of a person's family in the last name dependent caste system and it is impossible to change one's caste.

> I fully agree with the educated classes in India that a thorough
> overhauling of society is necessary. But how to do it? The destructive
> plans of reformers have failed. My plan is this. We have not done
> badly in the past, certainly not. Our society is not bad but good,
> only I want it to be better still. Not from error to truth, nor from
> bad to good, but from truth to higher truth, from good to better,
> best. I tell my countrymen that so far they have done well — now is
> the time to do better.
>
> Now, take the case of caste — in Sanskrit, Jâti, i.e. species. **Now,
> this is the first idea of creation. Variation (Vichitratâ), that is to
> say Jati, means creation. "I am One, I become many" (various Vedas).
> Unity is before creation, diversity is creation. Now if this diversity
> stops, creation will be destroyed. So long as any species is vigorous
> and active, it must throw out varieties. When it ceases or is stopped
> from breeding varieties, it dies. Now the original idea of Jati [i.e.
> Varna] was this freedom of the individual to express his nature, his
> Prakriti, his Jati, his caste;** and so it remained for
> thousands of years. Not even in the latest books is inter-dining
> prohibited; nor in any of the older books is inter-marriage forbidden.
> Then what was the cause of India's downfall? — the giving up of this
> idea of caste. As Gitâ says, with the extinction of caste
> the world will be destroyed. Now does it seem true that with
> the stoppage of these variations the world will be destroyed? The
> present caste is not the real Jati, but a hindrance to its
> progress. It really has prevented the free action of Jati, i.e. caste
> or variation. Any crystallized custom or privilege or
> hereditary class in any shape really prevents caste
> from having its full sway; and whenever any nation ceases to produce
> this immense variety, it must die. Therefore what I have to tell you,
> my countrymen, is this, that India fell because you prevented and
> abolished caste [Varna]. Every frozen aristocracy or privileged class
> is a blow to caste and is not-caste. Let Jati
> have its sway; break down every barrier in the way of caste,
> and we shall rise. Now look at Europe. When it succeeded in giving
> free scope to caste and took away most of the barriers that
> stood in the way of individuals, each developing his caste —
> Europe rose. In America, there is the best scope for caste
> to develop, and so the people are great. Every Hindu knows
> that astrologers try to fix the caste of every boy or girl as
> soon as he or she is born. That is the real caste — the individuality,
> and Jyotisha (astrology) recognises that. And we can only rise by
> giving it full sway again. This variety does not mean inequality, nor
> any special privilege.
>
> This is my method — to show the Hindus that they have to give up
> nothing, but only to move on in the line laid down by the sages and
> shake off their inertia, the result of centuries of servitude. Of
> course, we had to stop advancing during the Mohammedan tyranny, for
> then it was not a question of progress but of life and death. Now that
> that pressure has gone, we must move forward, not on the lines of
> destruction directed by renegades and missionaries, but along our own
> line, our own road. Everything is hideous because the building is
> unfinished. We had to stop building during centuries of oppression.
> Now finish the building and everything will look beautiful in its own
> place. This is all my plan. I am thoroughly convinced of this. Each
> nation has a main current in life; in India it is religion. Make it
> strong and the waters on either side must move along with it. This is
> one phase of my line of thought. In time, I hope to bring them all
> out, but at present I find I have a mission in this country also.
> Moreover, I expect help in this country and from here alone. But up to
> date I could not do anything except spreading my ideas. Now I want
> that a similar attempt be made in India.

***The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 4, Writings Prose, A Plan of Work for India***

**Vivekananda on Purusha Sukta**

> The doctrine of caste in the Purusha-Sukta of the Vedas does not make
> it hereditary..

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 6, Epistles, Second Series, VIII.**

**Vivekananda's opinion about Smritis on the caste issue** is given in a 30th May, 1897 letter to Sri. Pramada Das Mitra.

> **The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited
> intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors, the feelings of class
> and malice.** Only parts of them breathing broadness of spirit and love
> are acceptable, the rest are to be rejected. The Upanishads and the
> Gita are the true scriptures.

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 6/Epistles - Second Series/CXXIV**

Vivekananda thinks that the Rg Vedic text is talking about variation in human nature as can be seen from the letter to the Justice.

Comment: Can you reduce the size of the blockquote down to the part that actually addresses the question? (i.e., without the introduction/conclusion) 'As Gita says, with the extinction of caste the world will be destroyed.' - so he wanted the caste-system to continue in a new form? How does he interpret 'varnasankara' mentioned in the Gita? Is he in support of 'varnasankara' or opposed to it? In the new 'karma-guna based varna system' what exactly does varnasankara mean?

Comment: @sv, I have reduced the blockquote. Hopefully this will suffice. Vivekananda's caste system which he wants to continue is called meritocracy in other cultures. His example of Europe is to compare the triumph of meritocracy in Europe with the deleterous effect of the jati system of India. What he is saying is that the world will be destroyed if meritocracy is not encouraged. Varnasankar is mentioned by Arjuna. No one reads the Gita to know what Arjuna who stands for the common man is saying.

Comment: What exactly does Varna sankara mean in the karma-guna Varna system? It means that marriage between 2 persons would be successful if there is mental compatibility. If two persons are not mentally compatible then the chance of the marriage failing becomes high.

Comment: Thanks for reducing the size of blockquote. 'Vivekananda thinks that the Rg Vedic text is talking about variation in human nature as can be seen from the letter to the Justice.' - In the blockquote, I think he's just commenting on the general idea of caste/jati/varna, not specifically about Purusha Sukta. Do you know if commented specially on Purusha Sukta?

Comment: I have added a brief comment by Vivekananda on the Purusha Sukta.

Comment: What is the point of adding the Purusha Sukta ref. after seeing it in my answer? @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: I saw it after adding it. Actually I have read that letter many years ago and had forgotten about it.

Comment: My question above has been wrongfully closed as unclear/needs more focus, can you please reopen it?

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay That's hardly believable although I'm ready to trust you. But that does not change the fact that that part of your answer is technically a 'not an answer". Because you are reproducing exactly the same content that is already found in another previously existing answer.

Comment: OK @Rickross, I have edited my answer. Hope this is now satisfactory. Actually it is difficult to avoid overlap in this particular issue.

Comment: You shouldn't have to edit/remove content you added on your own. There is no such rule that content already posted in another answer cannot be reused. The other answer doesn't hold copyrights to Vivekananda's commentary.

Comment: Thank you @sv for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

> How did he interpret the Puruṣa-sūkta verse brāhmaṇo 'sya mukham ...
> padbhyāṃ śūdro ajāyata (brāhmaṇa was born from Puruṣa's mouth ...
> śūdra from his feet)?

According to Swami Vivekananda, the Purusha Sukta does not imply a birth based caste system.

He has mentioned this specifically in one of his letters. However, he does not elucidate why we should believe in what he is saying.

> DEAR SIR,
>
> It is more than a week since I received your letter, but having had
> another attack of fever, I could not send a reply all this time, for
> which please excuse me. For an interval of a month and a half I kept
> well, but I have suffered again for the last ten days; now I am doing
> well.
>
> I have certain questions to put, and you, sir, have a wide knowledge
> of Sanskrit; so please favour me with answers to the following:
>
> 1. Does any narrative occur about Satyakâma, son of Jabâlâ, and about Jânashruti, anywhere else in the Vedas excepting the Upanishads?[1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32325/4732)
> 2. In most cases where Shankaracharya quotes Smriti in his commentary on the Vedânta-Sutras, he cites the authority of the Mahâbhârata. **But
>    seeing that we find clear proofs about caste being based on
>    qualification** both in the Bhishmaparva of the Mahabharata and in the
>    stories there of the Ajagara and of Umâ and Maheshvara, has he made
>    any mention in his writings of this fact?
> 3. **The doctrine of caste in the Purusha-Sukta of the Vedas does not make it hereditary—so what are those instances in the Vedas where
>    caste has been made a matter of hereditary transmission?**

> [Source](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_6/Epistles_-_Second_Series/VIII_Sir) --- The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume
> 6/Epistles Second Series/VIII Sir

The highlighted portion in 2. also clearly depicts that he believes in a Guna (qualification) based caste system but he himself is not entirely sure about it. It is clear from his words that he is not fully aware of what is the overall view of scriptures on the issue and that's why he is seeking opinions of a Pundit in Sanskrit asking him to give him examples from the scriptures where the caste system is mentioned as birth based.

And, his opinions on the Smritis (Manu Smriti etc.) are already given in this [answer of mine](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32325/4732).

Comment: yeah, Swami Vivekananda's stance is like this : "If you become PM (enlightened/jivanmukta/moksha), you need not obey traffic red lights, but if you're not PM (in samsara), then you must obey red lights (Smritis). So traffic red lights are not that very important, just focus on becoming PM". It's not a practical answer to problems faced daily by normal people. But I understand his stance, because most people are just lazy and ok with getting stuck in traffic lights, and don't even think about escaping it.

Comment: what i don't understand is this : if varna is based only on guna, then what is guna based on ? people keep on saying birth-based vs guna-based. I don't see much distinction between the two for vast majority of people. If there is a distinction, that's because the birth itself is a slightly confused one (inter-mixing/varna-sankara). For e.g. the most common cited Vishvamitra himself was the result of a mix up of Charu. It was meant for brahmin birth but given to a kshatriya woman.

Comment: Guna is again based on birth lol (soil-seed example) .. this I have explained very clearly in one of my earlier answers. This Guna based caste system is the most absurd, illogical thing I have ever heard. @ram It is not accepting the fundamentals of Hinduism viz: Karma Doctrine. And, that's why no real Pundits of Hinduism advocate it. And it is not followable too in practical life. So, it is specifically for only those people who do debates but do not practice Hinduism.

Comment: exactly.. the only people i have seen propagating guna-based caste system seem to be anti-god/anti-hindu/anti-brahmin. i strongly believe that birth is necessary, but not sufficient to be recognized as a member of any varna, in all except rare circumstances, i.e. both birth and guna are requirements. the only place where guna-alone is a requirement is bhakti. if someone has deep devotion to God, only then his birth doesn't matter. But if we want to compare two people without devotion, or having same level of devotion, then birth & guna both definitely come into account.

Comment: I think no serious practitioner denies that how you lived  your past lives determine where you are born in this life. The core question is whether someone born to non-dvija/shudra parents be eligible for thread ceremony. I have come across both interpretations of the dvija-thread ceremony eligibility verse. Some say anyone can undergo it in childhood, and others say only those born to dvija parents. Ofcourse bhakti path leading to moksha is for everyone irrespective of birth - no doubt on that one.

Comment: @Carmensandiego, *"Some say anyone can undergo it in childhood"* - which traditional acharya says this ? the very word 'dvija' means 2 janmas - 2nd birth is upanayana. and only the 3 varnas are explicitly referred to as dvijas.

Comment: @ram - Arya samaj for one. Ofcourse they may not qualify as traditional, but in this day n age even they look traditional . And the example that keeps floating around is Satyakama Jabala. Even if we assume Gautama realizing that his father was a brahmin (and for argument sake assume that anuloma born are also eligible for upanayana)  the fact that Jabala's father carried out the act with a prostitute (without marrying her) made the Brahmin father  lose his varna - so any progeny cannot be considered Brahmin born

Comment: @Carmensandiego, jabala is an exception to the rule. like vishvamitra was. if you have enough tapas, you can change varna within same birth. it's a one in a yuga chance.

Comment: @ram - I too believe that guna and birth are linked. No doubt birth plays a role in determining yoiur proclivity towards a particular varna. However the breaking hindu forces have been relentless for over a century now with the narrative that brahmins oppressed shudras. They have conveniently ignore the fact that expectations are higher for brahmin and lower for shudras. Thus example of Jabala who does not have any extra ordinary circumstances surrounding his birth seems apt to shut them down.

Comment: @Carmensandiego, maybe so, but it also opens the can of worms that anyone can become any varna within any time.

Comment: @ram - Look around you. Do you see any non-brahmin born complaining that he is not being allowed to chant vedic mantras ? Even if I get the example of Jabala broadcast on national television everyday for next one year, it won't make a difference.

Comment: @Carmensandiego, i think you're missing the point. the point of varna system based on birth, is to 'lock-down' the people into doing the occupations of their birth varna. While superficially this 'lock-down' sounds like oppression, it is actually best-suited for them. if we say that anyone can become anything, it is giving free reign for the brahmins to pursue business, for vaishyas to pursue battle, shudras to pursue rituals etc. You're worrying about external breaking-hindu forces. i'm worried about internal. and if internal is strong, external can do ghanta about it..

Comment: @ram - Yes, i do see the point. But i am just talking about contemporary situation. I see many brahmin sounding last names who go around deriding Hinduism. The signal being sent out that if those who seemingly benefit from the system are against it then for sure there is something wrong. So for me first order of business is to counter such folks spewing hatred and discontent.